# Filtering simultaneously on count of related objects and on count of related objects that satisfy a condition in Django

Tags: sql, django, orm

So I have models amounting to this (very simplified, obviously):

```
class Mystery(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Character(models.Model):
    mystery = models.ForeignKey(Mystery, related_name="characters")
    required = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Basically, in each mystery there are a number of characters, which can be essential to the story or not. The minimum number of actors that can stage a mystery is the number of required characters for that mystery; the maximum number is the number of characters total for the mystery.

Now I'm trying to query for mysteries that can be played by some given number of actors. It seemed straightforward enough using the way Django's filtering and annotation features function; after all, both of these queries work fine:

```
# Returns mystery objects with at least x characters in all
Mystery.objects.annotate(max_actors=Count('characters', distinct=True)).filter(max_actors__gte=x)

# Returns mystery objects with no more than x required characters
Mystery.objects.filter(characters__required=True).annotate(min_actors=Count('characters', distinct=True)).filter(min_actors__lte=x)
```

However, when I try to combine the two...

```
Mystery.objects.annotate(max_actors=Count('characters', distinct=True)).filter(characters__required=True).annotate(min_actors=Count('characters', distinct=True)).filter(min_actors__lte=x, max_actors__gte=x)
```

...it doesn't work. Both min_actors and max_actors come out containing the maximum number of actors. The relevant parts of the actual query being run look like this:

```
SELECT `mysteries_mystery`.`id`,
    `mysteries_mystery`.`name`,
    COUNT(DISTINCT `mysteries_character`.`id`) AS `max_actors`,
    COUNT(DISTINCT `mysteries_character`.`id`) AS `min_actors`
FROM `mysteries_mystery`
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `mysteries_character` ON (`mysteries_mystery`.`id` = `mysteries_character`.`mystery_id`)
    INNER JOIN `mysteries_character` T5 ON (`mysteries_mystery`.`id` = T5.`mystery_id`)
WHERE T5.`required` = True
GROUP BY `mysteries_mystery`.`id`, `mysteries_mystery`.`name`
```

...which makes it clear that while Django is creating a second join on the character table just fine (the second copy of the table being aliased to T5), that table isn't actually being used anywhere and both of the counts are being selected from the non-aliased version, which obviously yields the same result both times.

Even when I try to use an `extra` clause to select from T5, I get told there is no such table as T5, even as examining the output query shows that it's still aliasing the second character table to T5. Another attempt to do this with `extra` clauses went like this:

```
Mystery.objects.annotate(max_actors=Count('characters', distinct=True)).extra(select={'min_actors': "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mysteries_character WHERE required = True AND mystery_id = mysteries_mystery.id"}).extra(where=["`min_actors` <= %s", "`max_actors` >= %s"], params=[x, x])
```

But that didn't work because I can't use a calculated field in the WHERE clause, at least on MySQL. If only I could use HAVING, but alas, Django's .extra() [does not and will never](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10702) allow you to set HAVING parameters.

Is there any way to get Django's ORM to do what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a couple of weeks with no suggested solutions, so here's how I ended up going about it, for anyone else who might be looking for an answer:

```
Mystery.objects.annotate(max_actors=Count('characters', distinct=True)).filter(max_actors__gte=x, id__in=Mystery.objects.filter(characters__required=True).annotate(min_actors=Count('characters', distinct=True)).filter(min_actors__lte=x).values('id'))
```

In other words, filter on the first count and on IDs that match those in an explicit subquery that filters on the second count. Kind of clunky, but it works well enough for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

How about combining your Count()s:

```
Mystery.objects.annotate(max_actors=Count('characters', distinct=True),min_actors=Count('characters', distinct=True)).filter(characters__required=True).filter(min_actors__lte=x, max_actors__gte=x)
```

This seems to work for me but I didn't test it with your exact models.

Comment: No; again, it just returns the total number of characters for both. It would be strange if this worked, anyway, seeing as Django has no way of knowing which of max_actors and min_actors is supposed to be counting which statistic if they're both together and set to perform identical Count()s.